# Error No value specified for parameter 1;

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Here is my code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (CEREVENTID,TRANSACTIONID,CLIENTCREDENTIALSID,EVENTDATETIME,SENTDATETIME,AUXID,CLIENTID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

this.getNetezzaJDBCTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() 
{
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException 
    {
        Event event = events.get(i);
        ps.setLong(1, event.getCEREventID());
        ps.setLong(2, event.getTransactionID());
        ps.setLong(3, event.getClientCredentialsID());
        ps.setTimestamp(4, event.getEventDateTime());
        ps.setTimestamp(5, event.getSentDateTime());
        ps.setLong(6, event.getAuxID());
        ps.setString(7, event.getClientID() );
    }

    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() 
    {
        return events.size();
    }
}
```

It is throwing an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO TABLE1 (CEREVENTID,TRANSACTIONID,CLIENTCREDENTIALSID,EVENTDATETIME,SENTDATETIME,AUXID,CLIENTID)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL state [HY010]; error code [11410]; No value specified for parameter 1; nested exception is org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:890)
    at com.omnitracs.fra.dao.EventDAO.insertEvents(EventDAO.java:117)
    at com.omnitracs.fra.main.CriticalEventMain.main(CriticalEventMain.java:76)
Caused by: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
    at org.netezza.internal.NzPreparedQuery.toNativeString(NzPreparedQuery.java:627)
    at org.netezza.internal.QueryExecutor.sendQuery(QueryExecutor.java:450)
    at org.netezza.internal.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:72)
    at org.netezza.sql.NzConnection.execute(NzConnection.java:2673)
    at org.netezza.sql.NzStatement._execute(NzStatement.java:849)
    at org.netezza.sql.NzStatement._executeUpdate(NzStatement.java:860)
    at org.netezza.sql.NzPreparedStatament.executeBatch(NzPreparedStatament.java:991)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:905)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:890)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
... 4 more
```

I have cut down the total number of fields/columns to 7 (from 66) so it is easier to troubleshoot but still no luck.

How do I debug this? Please help.

Comment: Is CEREventId initialized?

Comment: are parameters indexed starting a zero?

Comment: To start with I'd check whether `setValues(...)` is called and if `event.getCEREventID()` returns null for some event (on a second thought, the signature of `setLong(...)` is `void setLong(int parameterIndex, long x) throws SQLException;`, thus you'd get a NPE if `event.getCEREventID()` returned null).

Comment: @TMcKeown no, PreparedStatement indices are 1-based.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry not sure what you mean. You mean one of the records has a NULL from event.getCEREventID()?

Comment: @Ram yes, but read the addition to my comment, in that case you should get a NPE.